# How to use max, min functions in projection.columnName.range to the AWS Glue Table Property

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, azure-data-catalog

I use the below table property to set range to date column

```
'projection.date.range' = 'NOW-365DAYS,NOW+1DAYS'
```

The table has no data from NOW-365DAYS as it is a new table. While querying from Athena on this table results in a high volume of listbucket requests. I don't want to happen this. SO thought to set a range like below

`'projection.date.range' = 'MAX(2022/01/12, NOW-365DAYS), NOW+1DAYS'` so that i can avoid empty partitions. But it is throwing me an error.

Is there a way to use MAX/MIN functions in `projection.date.range`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to qualify the partition projection range like that, unfortunately. I suggest setting the lower bound to the actual first date with data until the relative range makes sense.

Since you say Athena is making a lot of S3 list requests I assume you are querying the table without filters on this partition key. This will always result in a lot of S3 listings, at least 365 of them, regardless of whether there is data or not. Why aren't your queries filtering on the `date` partition key?

Is the reason why you want the range to be the last 365 days that you will remove data after one year, or is there another reason?